# How to return a list of pairs from an arraylist Java

Tags: java, list

I have the following list of `Integers`

```
(0,1,2,3)
```

Now I want to write a method which returns specific number of pairs from the list. So if I give it `5` as argument I will expect it to return the following:

```
(0,1),(1,2),(2,3),(3,0),(0,1)
```

So basically starts with the first two elements of the list and when it reaches the end element and another pair is needed, then it should pair the last element of the list with the first one and continue.

Any ideas how can I implement this?

**And if someone can explain to me why do I get that many down votes that would be great??**

Comment: the suggested question doesn't help much

Comment: Okay. I actually submitted it accidentally, before getting to take a look at it more closely. Deleted.

Comment: ah the downvote is because most probably people haven't seen what you have tried. Try posting the code that you've tried and the error and people will be glad to help you out =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At first I thought that this is a complex problem but at the end it turned out to be very easy. Here`s the code for it :

```
List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(0);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(2);
    list.add(3);

    int counter = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++){

        counter++;



        if (list.get(i) == list.max()){

            System.out.println(i + "," + list.get(0));
            i=0;
        }

        System.out.println(i + "," + (i+1));

        if (counter==5){
        break;
        }

    }

}
```